# Printing multiple pages all on one sheet

Tags: printing

I am having a problem with printing a document. I am in no way an expert at programming, but have been learning on my own for about a year now so I understand the basics. I think I know where the problem is but I don't know how to fix it and I have done my due diligence to find an answer without any luck.

I am trying to create a list of reports that the user is able to select the specific reports to be printed and then hit the print button or print preview button and have the reports print or be displayed as appropriate. When I have the print or print preview buttons connected to one specific report, it works fine. Once I change it to print from the list it starts giving me problems and the problem only occurs when the report is two or more pages long and it randomly happens without me making any changes. (sometimes it works fine and other times not) The problem is it will try to print all of the pages onto one sheet like a photo that has been double exposed. See screen shot below.

[image: example of problem]

Here is the code I believe to be important.

```
public class Report //Creates a new class called Report.
{
    public PrintDocument Document = new PrintDocument();

    private int LineNumber;
    private int PageNumber;
    private int TotalNumberOfPages;

    private PrintDocument Set() //Sets up the document.
    {
        Body.Add(new NewLine());
        LineNumber = 0;
        PageNumber = 1;
        Document.DocumentName = Title[0].Text;
        Document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(OnPrintPage);
        return Document;
    }
    private void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) //Sets up the lines to be printed.
    {
        int Offset = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        int PageEnd = e.MarginBounds.Top + e.MarginBounds.Height;

        //Instructions on how to build the page. Trust me, it's right.

        if (AllLines.Count > LineNumber)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            /* ^This is where the problem is problem is. When this is made true, it sometime changes back to 
              false (as it should) when it gets to the end, but sometime it does not. The times that it randomly 
              does not, it still starts the page over but does it right on top of the old page like I printed 
              the first page out, then put the paper back into the printer and printed the second page over it. 
            */
            PageNumber++;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false; 
            LineNumber = 0;
            PageNumber = 1; 
        }
    }

    public void Print() //Sets the command to send the document to the printer.
    {
        Set().Print();
    }
    public void PrintPreview() //Set the command to display the document.
    {
        PrintPreviewDialog PP = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        PP.Document = Set();
        PP.ShowDialog();
    }
}

public partial class frmReports : Form
{
#region PRINT DOCUMENTS //Creates the reports.
    public Report Report1()
    {
        Report Page = new Report();     
        //Instructions on how to build the page. Trust me, it's right.
        return Page;
    }   
    public Report Report2()
    {
        Report Page = new Report();     
        //Instructions on how to build the page. Trust me, it's right.
        return Page;
    }   
    public Report Report3()
    {
        Report Page = new Report();     
        //Instructions on how to build the page. Trust me, it's right.
        return Page;
    }
    public Report Report4()
    {
        Report Page = new Report();     
        //Instructions on how to build the page. Trust me, it's right.
        return Page;
    }
    public Report Report5()
    {
        Report Page = new Report();     
        //Instructions on how to build the page. Trust me, it's right.
        return Page;
    }
    #endregion

    List<Report> Reports = new List<Report>(); //Creates a Reports List

    public frmReports()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      

        //Adds the reports to the Reports List
        Reports.Add(Report1());
        Reports.Add(Report2());
        Reports.Add(Report3());
        Reports.Add(Report4());
        Reports.Add(Report5());

        foreach (Report r in Reports) //Adds the reports to the List Box already added to the form.
            lstReportList.Items.Add(r);
    }

    private void OnClick_btnPrint(object sender, EventArgs e) //When clicking the Print button.
    {
        if (lstReportList.SelectedItem != null) 
            foreach(Report r in Reports.FindAll(r => r == lstReportList.SelectedItem) r.Print(); //Determains all of the items in the List Box and prints them out.
    }

    private void OnClick_btnPrintPreview(object sender, EventArgs e) //When clicking the Print Preview button.
    {
        if (lstReportList.SelectedItem != null)
            foreach(Report r in Reports.FindAll(r => r == lstReportList.SelectedItem) r.PrintPreview(); //Determains all of the items in the List Box and displays them.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to reset the document.

```
    public void Print()
    {
        Set().Print();
        Document = new PrintDocument(); //<-------------
    }
    public void PrintPreview()
    {
        PrintPreviewDialog PP = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        PP.Document = Set();
        Form frmPP = (Form)PP;
        frmPP.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        PP.Name = PP.Document.DocumentName;
        frmPP.Text = PP.Name;
        frmPP.Icon = ((Icon)(Midas_Point_of_Sales_System.Properties.Resources.yellow));
        PP.ShowDialog();
        Document = new PrintDocument(); //<-------------
    }
```